# dask-yarn KilledWorker no meaningful traceback

Tags: python, hadoop-yarn, dask

I deployed dask on EMR using dask-yarn and the provided script in [dask's website](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html).
I try a simple `read` and `take` for avro file in my s3, but I get `KillerWorker` exception without clear meaning as to the cause of the error.

```
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster
cluster = YarnCluster(environment='environment.tar.gz',
                      worker_vcores=2,
                      worker_memory='4GB',
                      n_workers=4)
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import bag as db
client = Client(cluster)
av = db.read_avro('s3://path/to/fil.avro')
av.take(1)
```

Exception:

```
KilledWorker: ("('bag-from-delayed-read-avro-take-57f2529def40184e19b004eb8d459535', 0)", <Worker 'tcp://172.31.125.168:38215', memory: 0, processing: 1>)
```

Answer (score 0):

`KilledWorker` errors arise when your workers die unexpectedly repeatedly.  I encourage you to use the `yarn` API to inspect the logs of your workers.  Often this is caused by misconfigured software environments, but it could be many things.  Hopefully those logs help to point you in a productive direction.

Comment: The script inte dask-yarn website. Do you know which version of EMR it was tested upon?